# Using cell content to open up a file

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with input range and filenames.  I have a number of worksheets  2014...2018. I extract the year from today's date and I want to use the year to then set `inputRange` which spreadsheet I want to extract data from.  I put the year in Cell F1 but I get error messages.  Can someone help me?

Below is my code:

```
Set InputRange = Worksheets(Chr(34) & F1.Value & Chr(34)).Range("a4:a418")
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your title doesn't match the information you gave. Are these separate workbooks that you are trying to open or just worksheets in the same workbook? If it is the latter, see below. Otherwise you will need to edit the question you gave to make it more clear.

I would guess that the two chr(34) functions are unnecessary since the value of cell F1 is probably a string anyway. Also, unless somewhere above you set F1 to equal Worksheet.Range("F1"), that isn't how you would reference cell F1. A quick example is below, you will most likely need to edit it slightly to get it to actually work.

```
Dim F1 As Range
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim InputRange As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("base worksheet name")
Set F1 = ws.Range("F1")

Set InputRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(F1.Value).Range("A4:A418")
```